# Is "overloading" in "operator overloading" just semantic?

Tags: kotlin, idioms

Kotlin is one of the languages that allow us to easily define behavior for various predefined operators, operation named `operator overloading` - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html

My question is regarding the `overloading` part of the operation.

From what I see default the language only declares operators for the basic types - https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/01a613dca4042dde8d2374ff0e6610cb9eddc415/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Primitives.kt

If I'm reading this correctly our custom types would not have any of this special methods - operators available by default. And indeed if we're to try

```
class A { }
val a = A()
System.out.println(a + a)
```

the compiler would try to find a suitable `operator plus` method to call but ultimately give a compilation error.

But if we do declare our own `operator plus` method

```
class A { 
    operator fun plus(other: A) = "Hello!"
}
val a = A()
System.out.println(a + a)
```

we would indeed have "Hello!" printed.

The above mechanism is called "operator overloading" but without a previous method with the same name we do not in fact use the OOP method overloading we all are accustomed to - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading.

So between the two mechanisms - operator overloading and method overloading there is really no connection, other than an unfortunate name clash?

Comment: function overloading is a concept that can be applied outside of OOP for free functions as well. If you see the operator + as a free function then I don't think it's a completely seperate concept

Comment: Here's the crucial thing missing from your question. How do you define "overloading" in general? My working definition is *"to give a name or symbol different meanings for different types of operands"*. So are operator overloading and method overloading really different?

Comment: I don't know how overloading works in Kotlin, but you also tagged your question C++, and in C++ you can overload the operators as if they were normal functions. And, just as with normal functions, you need to declare them. But I'm not sure if your question is if there should be a default operator+ for your class A?

Comment: "*but without a previous method with the same name*" Wouldn't the method be called "operator plus"? There are many different functions with the same name, with the difference being that they take different variables.

Comment: @StoryTeller For me, overloading presumes already having a method, with name, parameters and return type. Then declaring another one with the same name but otherwise a changed signature.
For operator overloading I don't see an already existing method. So when we're doing "operator overloading" we're declaring a new method, we're not overloading an existing one.

Comment: Well, without *overloading* `plus` for your custom object the default behaviour is a compilation error. But you can *change* that behaviour… 

Comment: @Mugurel: "*For operator overloading I don't see an already existing method.*" And yet you do. You can add two things together of various types already, through functions provided by your compiler. Those are methods that already exist.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are confused about operators in general.

The thing about operators is that they are just inline **functions** and the operator keyword is just a language construct to give you the ability to group operators with classes.

Where you can find answers about this is definitely the source code. If we take a look at the tests, we can find the [following](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/b7e5d9faaeab8fe3bcba76d73558eb52ccc78f9e/idea/testData/quickfix/createFromUsage/createVariable/localVariable/nonIdentifier.kt):

```
// "Create local variable '-'" "false"
// ACTION: Create extension function 'A.minus'
// ACTION: Create member function 'A.minus'
// ACTION: Replace overloaded operator with function call
```

Sadly, I cannot find the source code where operator is transformed, but most certainly this must be the procedure where the operator overload is replaced with function call.